# Autoadjust ListView size

Tags: listview, javafx

The problem is that talles has only two elements, and in the scene the `ListView` has some empty cells. I want only to have cells as the length of the list.

```
options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(options.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
ListView<String> waistOptions = new ListView<String>();
System.out.println(waistOptions.getItems());
waistOptions.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
waistOptions.setMaxSize(426,30);
waistOptions.getItems().addAll(options);
waistOptions.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty();
waistOptions.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
waistOptions.setFocusTraversable(false);
paneWaist.getChildren().addAll(waistOptions);
```

[image: ListView]

Answer (score 0):

in css file paste it

```css
.list-cell:empty {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
}
```